# RallyDev API:How to prevent password expiration for user accounts

Tags: rally

I am using the following SOAP API to interact with rally:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.40/RallyService

And I am using a Username/Password which expires every three months. I was wondering if there is any settings on user accounts in rally that could prevent it from expiring.

Thanks,
Varun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately a password expiration policy is required for all Rally UserID's. This is a commonly-requested feature however, to allow for more relaxed policies for automation users. This idea:

[Change password policy for single user account](https://ideas.rallydev.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?c=FB85CCBC-A755-42AD-AF8E-6F2B539BECEC&idea_id=9761A25C-9B05-44C2-A7AF-DC713EBBC76F)

On Rally Ideas corresponds to this feature request. I'd encourage for you and your teammates to vote on it to help raise visibility with Rally's product team.

Also - you may wish to explore porting your automation code to one of Rally's [REST-based toolkits](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/rest-apis).

Versions 2.0 and higher of Rally's Webservices will not include SOAP-based services. While SOAP will continue to be available in Webservices 1.x for a full year following the soon-to-be released Webservices 2.0, customers requiring new/updated Rally functionality will find that updates are no longer available in SOAP starting with version 2.0.